# AngularJS v1.2.21 ngAnimate for ngRepeat list

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-animate

I want to use Angulars animate module to sequentially populate the results from the following:

```
<div class="search-result" ng-repeat="plate in searchCtrl.results.plates">
    <p class="search-result-value">{{plate.value}}</p>
    ...
</div>
```

I have tried using the stagger technique but could not manage to get it to function properly.

The animate module is loading properly and the transitions *try* to work properly, but I must be doing something incorrectly.

Example:

::RESULTS::

(after .2s) Result 1

(+= .2s)    Result 2

(+= .2s)    Result 3

So basically instead of all of the results loading instantly, I want the first to load, then the second, then third.. etc. (Just simply displaying them one after another would work for this example, but fading in would be very nice!)

Thanks!

-- *Solution* --

I used the following angular-animate library

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.21/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

and then used the following CSS to get my staggered animation effect I desired

```
/* animations */
.search-result.ng-enter {
    transition: 0.3s ease-in all;
    transform: scale(0.8);
    opacity: 0;
}

.search-result.ng-enter-stagger {
    transition-delay: 0.09s;
    transition-duration: 0s;
}
.search-result.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know what are you doing wrong without seeing the rest of the code, but here comes an example.

HTML:

```
  <div ng-repeat="plate in plates" class="animation">
    <p class="search-result-value">{{plate.value}}</p>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.animation.ng-enter {
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.animation.ng-enter-stagger {
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.animation.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

**Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/kE3e47WRjE0zHo9P7AO2?p=preview

I hope it helps.

*Edit - Seems there is a bug affecting the 'Add five with initial delay'-case when using the minified version of angular-animate: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8297*

Comment: Right, I think you have the right idea, but your code is not working (because of the bug?). In the link you posted, rad commented below with a working exmaple of *exactly* what I am looking for. Perhaps mine is not working because of a bug? I will have to research further. +1 for the link.

Comment: After looking into the github forums at the link you posted, I am led to believe that it is a bug. I used the source code for an older version (1.2.13) of angular-animate and I got the proper results. I am going to forego any further investigation as I am on a tight time frame.. thank you!